# Google NDB model validation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How does one validate the GAE's no sql "ndb" model in python ?

Is there a pattern for this. Lets say I have a model called BreadCrumb

```
class BreadCrumb_Ndb(ndb.Model):
    """ A model for building breadcrumbs on the site """
    item_prop = ndb.StringProperty()
    item_type = ndb.StringProperty()
    href = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I want to validate the property href to ensure its of url format using regular expressions.

Comment: Where is the data coming from? A form?

Comment: Eventually yes it will come from a form.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options), ndb types take a `validator` argument which is used to validate/coerce the property's input. However, it's usually wiser to validate the submitted form (since that's what seems you intend to do) before attempting to insert it into the DB (WTForms is great for this use-case).

Comment: How should cross field validation be done? eg: Model has start_date and end_date and I want to ensure that start_date should be less than end_date.

Comment: @akshar I haven't used the engine for a while, but based on my answer I believe the `validator` is not meant for cross-validation but rather just type/format validation and coercion if necessary. In other words, you'll have to handle this prior to db insertion.

Answer (score 1):

WTForms might be exactly what you need as it'll even generate the form for you then check it on submission:

> With WTForms, your form field HTML can be generated for you, but we
>   let you customize it in your templates. This allows you to maintain
>   separation of code and presentation, and keep those messy parameters
>   out of your python code. Because we strive for loose coupling, you
>   should be able to do that in any templating engine you like, as well.
>   As your data is coming from a form you can use a custom validator in
>   WTForms
>   Here you'd need to add your custom validator for hrefs:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', [InputRequired()])

    def validate_name(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 50:
            raise ValidationError('Name must be less than 50 characters')
```

NDB is now supported: https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.4/ext.html

An alternative is detailed in this answer: [Evaluate a condition after put() in NDB and GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358728/evaluate-a-condition-after-put-in-ndb-and-gae)

where you would run a post-put hook to validate.

Comment: and here is an example with WTForms and Regular expression.. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25533370/8418

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in another answer, ndb Property subclasses accept a `validator` argument.

> Optional function to validate and possibly coerce the value.
>
> Will be called with arguments (prop, value) and should either return
>   the (possibly coerced) value or raise an exception. Calling the
>   function again on a coerced value should not modify the value further.
>   (For example, returning value.strip() or value.lower() is fine, but
>   not value + '$'.) May also return None, which means "no change".

ref: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#options

It is best to apply your validation as close to the data as possible. This will prevent non-form data entry tasks from being able to corrupt your fields. Something similar to this should work:

```
from urlparse import urlsplit
def is_url(prop, value):
    o = urlsplit(value)
    if not o.scheme or not o.netloc:
        raise Exception("{} is not a valid URL".format(value))
    return value

class BreadCrumb_Ndb(ndb.Model):
    """A model for building breadcrumbs on the site"""
    item_prop = ndb.StringProperty()
    item_type = ndb.StringProperty()
    href = ndb.StringProperty(validator=is_url)
```

Comment: How should cross field validation be done? eg: Model has start_date and end_date and I want to ensure that start_date should be less than end_date.

Answer (score 1):

If cross field validation is needed, then probably overriding put() is the quickest way.

```
def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.start_date > self.end_date:
        raise Exception("start_date must be less than end_date")
    return super(BaseModel, self).put(*args, **kwargs)
```